# Greek and special characters show as mojibake - how to decode?

Tags: character-encoding, decoding, corrupt, mojibake, text-decoding

I'm trying to figure out how to decode some corrupt characters I have in a spreadsheet. There is a list of website titles: some in English, some in Greek, some in other languages. For example, Greek phrase `ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΑ ΝΕΑ ΤΩΡΑ` shows as `ŒïŒõŒõŒóŒùŒôŒöŒë ŒùŒïŒë Œ§Œ©Œ°Œë`. So the whitespaces are OK, but the actual letters gone all wrong.

I have noticed that letters got converted to pairs of symbols:

- `Ε` - `Œï`
- `Λ` - `Œõ`

And so on. So it's almost always `Œ` and then some other symbol after it.

I went further, removed the repeated letter and checked difference in ASCII codes of the actual phrase and what was left of the corrupted phrase: `ord('ï') - ord('Ε')` and so on. The difference is *almost* the same all the time: `

```
678
678
678
676
676
677
676
678
0 (this is a whitespace)
676
678
678
0 (this is a whitespace)
765
768
753
678
```

I have manually decoded some of the other letters from other titles:

```
Greek

Œë  Α
Œî  Δ
Œï  Ε
Œõ  Λ
Œó  Η
Œô  Ι
Œö  Κ
Œù  Ν
Œ°  Ρ
Œ§  Τ
Œ©  Ω
Œµ  ε
Œª  λ
œÑ  τ
ŒØ  ί
Œø  ο
œÑ  τ
œâ  ω
ŒΩ  ν

Symbols

‚Äò ‘
‚Äô ’
‚Ä¶ …
‚Ä† †
‚Äú “

Other

√©  é
```

It's good I have a translation for this phrase, but there are a couple of others I don't have translation for. I would be glad to see any kind of advice because searching around StackOverflow didn't show me anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a character encoding issue. The string appears to be in encoding [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) (figured it out by educated guesses on [this site](https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx)). The IANA code for this encoding is `macintosh`, and its Windows code page number is 100000.

Here's a Python function that will decode `macintosh` to `utf-8` strings:

```py
def macToUtf8(s):
  return bytes(s, 'macintosh').decode('utf-8')

print(macToUtf8('ŒïŒõŒõŒóŒùŒôŒöŒë ŒùŒïŒë Œ§Œ©Œ°Œë'))
# outputs: ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΑ ΝΕΑ ΤΩΡΑ
```

My best guess is that your spreadsheet was saved on a Mac Computer, or perhaps saved using some Macintosh-based setting.

See also this issue: [What encoding does MAC Excel use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14327920/)

Comment: Thank you so much! The spreadsheet is a Google Spreadsheets document so it is hosted online, I'm not sure how was it saved. Maybe it was imported from a file. Thank you.

Comment: @pgndck Ah, importing the Google Sheet from a Mac sounds plausible. Is the Python solution ok? Or would it be better as an App Script or other?